# Is there a way to export semantic className on build with styled-components?

Tags: styled-components

const ComponentName = styled.div``;

Can we get the class name like class="ComponentName" in the output html instead of having class="btf79-fhjas MkrI" classe names?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the styled components-name in the google devtools, I want to share an easy solution for that:

1. Install the Babbel plug-in like this: `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components`
2. If you are usind ***create-react-app*** you should write
   `import styled from "styled-components/macro";` in the top-section of every component, that you wish to use styled components in.

As a result the name of the styled component will be show as the elements className in the devtools